# How do I update aws cli from v1 to v2 on Ubuntu? Amazon's official instructions don't work

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am running Ubuntu under WSL2 on Windows 11 and building an AWS CDK project.  I recently discovered that I needed to update my AWS CLI from version 1 to 2.  I followed the letter the [official AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html), but it didn't work.  After following it and running `aws --version`, it is still showing the following (thus indicating that I am still running under v1):

`aws-cli/1.22.34 Python/3.10.12 Linux/4.4.0-22621-Microsoft botocore/1.34.43`

I tried everything again, and after downloading the package and executing `sudo ./aws/install`, I get the message: `Found same AWS CLI version: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/2.15.27. Skipping install.`

So the above error is saying I already have v2 installed, which is in contradiction to what I see when I run `aws --version`.

Why is this happening?  I expected that upgrading my aws cli version would be a simple one-line command (i.e. just like updating `npm`).  Why did Amazon have to make this so complicated?

How do I fix this?

Comment: I would personally not even attempt to update the awscli. I would uninstall it (and what that process is depends upon how you originally installed it) and then install v2. BTW I suspect that these 'update' instructions relate to within the major version (e.g. from 2.0.1 to 2.0.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

```
/usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws --version
```

and you can verify that you have v2 installed and running.

The problem is that your `PATH` contains v1 before, so when you run just `aws` that's the version found.